# Way to trigger input type file with a default file

Tags: jquery

I am having trouble while triggering an input type file with a  default file name, I tried something like the code given below.

```
$('#fileinput').trigger('click', 'file-name');
```

Comment: i need to trigger the field with default file, I am able to trigger the input field with click. But i failed to trigger the input field with a specific file.

Comment: I have a form field with input file field which receives an image as an input. Upon form submit, it goes to server. Then i need to have a edit option for the same form.. So while on edit, i need to trigger the image upload field with the already uploaded image. Thats the present scenario

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this

```js
$("#fileinput").click(function(){
    $("input").trigger("select");
});
```